# Can UnicastRemoteObject be exported and then passed as argument

Tags: java, client-server, rmi, remote-access, remote-server

I have a client server structure. The server exposes a service with RMI, let's say it is: `RemoteInterfaceA`. The service is regualary exported using `UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(service, port)` and bound in the RMI Registry.

The server however must update something in the client so also the client creates a `RemoteInterfaceB`, it exports it using `UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(update, port)`. It cannot however create a Registry (because unlike the server it is not reachable from the internet). To give to the server its update stub, I pass the update as an argument of a service (`RemoteInterfaceA`) method.

Will it work?

Comment: Worth noting that with this setup the client is also considered a server and should be thought about as one in terms of accessibility.

Answer (score 1):

It will work, firewalls permitting. As you say the client isn't reachable from the Internet, it won't for you. The server will get a `NetworkUnreachableException` or a connect timeout when it tries to callback the client.